# How to find multiple indexes in array of objects by the value of an object property that nests in a property of array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, find

I have an array of objects, each object has a property of "watched" that is an array of objects by itself.

```
let arr = 
        [ 
            {   
                id: 1, 
                name: "A", 
                watched: [ 
                            {movieId: 7, movieName: "Avatar"} , 
                            {movieId: 8, movieName: "Titanic"}
                        ]
            },
            {   
                id: 2, 
                name: "B", 
                watched: [   
                            {movieId: 1, movieName: "Armageddon"} , 
                            {movieId: 8, movieName: "Titanic"}
                        ]
            },
            {   
                id: 3, 
                name: "C", 
                watched: [   
                            {movieId: 1, movieName: "Armageddon"} , 
                            {movieId: 7, movieName: "Avatar"}
                        ]
            }

        ]
```

I need an array of indexes according to a given MovieId.
If I want an array of indexes who watched movieId no. 7 (Avatar) -
I'll get:

let AvatarWatchers = [0,2]

I tried:

```
AvatarWatchers = arr.filter((item) => item.watched.find(movieObj => movieObj.movieId == 7) > -1 )
```

But It's not working and I'm getting an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = 
        [ 
            {   
                id: 1, 
                name: "A", 
                watched: [ 
                            {movieId: 7, movieName: "Avatar"} , 
                            {movieId: 8, movieName: "Titanic"}
                        ]
            },
            {   
                id: 2, 
                name: "B", 
                watched: [   
                            {movieId: 1, movieName: "Armageddon"} , 
                            {movieId: 8, movieName: "Titanic"}
                        ]
            },
            {   
                id: 3, 
                name: "C", 
                watched: [   
                            {movieId: 1, movieName: "Armageddon"} , 
                            {movieId: 7, movieName: "Avatar"}
                        ]
            }

        ];

let result = arr.map((item, index) => ({...item, index}))
            .filter(item => item.watched.find(watchedItem => watchedItem.movieName === 'Avatar'))
            .map(item => item.index);

console.log('expected result', result);
```